# Custom method for ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello I would like to make a custom method for ArrayList class.

So lets say I make a new ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>
```

I would like to make a method I can call on list. 
Something like this:

```
list.myMethod();
```

What I want to solve with my method is so you can get an Object by Object name and not index inside the ArrayList.

So basically I want to make a method returning following:

```
list.get(list.indexOf(str));
```

To sum it up:

```
    ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<>();
    String str = "asd";
    String str2 = "zxc";
    list.add(str2);
    list.add(str);
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
    System.out.println(list.get(list.indexOf(str)));
```

Will print: "asd" "asd".

So instead of writing: `list.get(list.indexOf(Object))`
I would like to be a able to write `list.myMethod(Object)` and get the same result. I hope you understand my question. I know this is probably a dumb solution and I could just use a Map. But this is for learning purpose only and nothing I will use.

Comment: Create your own class extending the `ArrayList` and use it or you can always create a static method that will do the same thing like `public static Object find(Object o, List l){ return l.get(l.indexOf(o));}`, this is a bit messy of course

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this. Say you have a list: `{"cat", "dog", "mouse"}`. You want to be able to call `list.myMethod("cat");` to get a string containing "cat"? You already have a string containing "cat"! You passed it to the method.

Comment: "Don't use the example to understand" - what is the point of the example then? This question makes no sense when used in the context of strings. Also I've never heard any use the term "object name" before. It's not up to me to infer details missing from the question: it's OP's responsibility to make sure I don't have to.

Comment: @Michael Im sry I dont use the correct language. But I have now solved my issue and can consider this case as closed. I was just curious If I could do it. You can see my accepted answer with the added comment. But this is nothing I will considering using because of the performance lost. In a real case I would probably just use a map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Custom method >>**

```
public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    public E getLastItem(){
        return get(size()-1);
    }

}
```

**How to use it >>**

```
MyArrayList<String> list= new MyArrayList<>();
String str = "asd";
String str2 = "zxc";
list.add(str2);
list.add(str);
System.out.println(list.getLastItem());
```

Comment: I will accept this as answer but I just changed your method to following: `public E superGet(Object o){
        return get(indexOf(o));
    }`

Comment: @Kerwin, you should explain the solution. I know this is simple but if someone search for this, this is not simple for them ;)

Answer (score 3):

what you need requires to extend the ArrayList classs, but you should consider using instead a

```
Map<String, Object>
```

with that approach you can do something like

```
myMap.get("myObject1");
```

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ Yea I know I could use a map but as I wrote "I know this is probably a dumb solution and I could just use a Map. But this is for learning purpose only and nothing I will use."

Answer (score 3):

You should just extend the `ArrayList` class creating your own with the new method. But the performance would be horrible if your list grow too much. The `indexOf` method have O(n), so greater is the size of your array longer is the time you have to wait.

May be you should choose a different collection if you want access directly to the element. In your case, it elements stored in the collection are unique, you could use a `Set`.

On the other hand, a `Set` does not preserve the insertion order. I don't know if this is a think you have to care of.

And a `Set` just let you know if the element is contained into the collection.

Another collection that can be of your interest is the `Map`, this is a key-value collection.

But given that you have only keys this it seems not be your case.

Comment: Have a look at [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) or [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), those preserve insertion order and let you have O(1) access time.