# Custom HashMap by extending

Tags: java, hashmap

> **Question:** How do you create a custom HashMap class, extending HashMap, that can be manipulated like normal?

Let me explain. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227956/custom-method-for-arraylist), you can create custom methods with ArrayLists by extending ArrayList and then writing your method. How would I do that with HashMaps?

I want to create a UserList class that can be initialized with `UserList users = new HashMap<Users, Integer>`. This is my class for UserList so far:

```
public class UserList extends HashMap<Users, Integer> {

    public Users getUser(UUID uuid) {
        for (Users u: keySet()) {
            if (u.getUuid().equals(uuid))
                return u;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Boolean containsPlayer(UUID uuid) {
        for (Users u: keySet()) {
            if (u.getUuid().equals(uuid))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public Users removeUser(UUID uuid) {
        for (Users u: keySet()) {
            if (u.getUuid().equals(uuid)) {
                remove(u);
                return u;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

But whenever I type private `UserList listOfUsers = new HashMap<Users, Integer>;` in the main class, it brings up an incompatible type error. How do I fix this? I remember learning about this before, but I've since forgotten.

Thanks

Comment: You can not assign parent class object into the child class. Here HashMap is parent class and UserList is child class. you should use UserList listOfUsers = new UserList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UserList users = new UserList()`, no need for anything else.

By extending the `HashMap` you already told the compiler that `UserList` is a `HashMap`.

As a suggestion, you may want to consider composition as an alternative design: [Composition over inharitance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: Happens to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is about extending HashMap, but you can achieve the same by encapsulating the HashMap implementation inside your object:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

public class UserList  {
    private Map<UUID, Users> users;

    public UserList() {
        this.users = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Users getUser(UUID uuid) {
        return this.users.getOrDefault(uuid, null);
    }

    public Users removeUser(UUID uuui){
        return this.users.remove(uuui);
    }

    public Boolean containsPlayer(UUID uuid) {
        return this.users.keySet().contains(uuid);
    }

    public Users addUser(UUID uuid, Users users) {
        return this.users.put(uuid, users);
    }
}

class Users{}

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserList userList = new UserList();
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        Users users = new Users();
        userList.addUser(uuid, users);
        userList.removeUser(uuid);
        userList.containsPlayer(uuid);
    }
}
```